# Debian - cannot find cdrom

Tags: debian, devices, data-cd

Having a jessie/sid debian box on kernel 3.13 (had same issue on kernel 3.10) First thing I notices was that k3b didn't find any optical drives.

Then:
The optical drives (dvd-writers) are found in the bios (connected on pata - worked sometimes earlier, but I don't know what has been updated since that - quite a lot probably) 
but

- `dmsesg | grep CD` (or `grep cd` / `dvd` / `DVD`) does not show any trace of them
- `wodim -scanbus` returns a "Cannot open SCSI driver!"
- `lsmod` shows that `sr_mod` and `sd_mod` are loaded.

Looking a bit closer in dmesg, I find:

```
[    0.629414] pata_jmicron 0000:05:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0001)
[    0.632751] scsi2 : pata_jmicron
[    0.634988] scsi3 : pata_jmicron
[    0.635060] ata3: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xbf00 ctl 0xbe00 bmdma 0xbb00 irq 17
[    0.635063] ata4: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xbd00 ctl 0xbc00 bmdma 0xbb08 irq 17
```

Where at last the PATA interface seems to be found. Only the optical drives are connected through pata, all hdds on this system are sata.

lsmod | grep sr gives me:

```
morten@sorbus:~$ lsmod |grep sr
sr_mod                 21898  0 
cdrom                  39232  1 sr_mod
scsi_mod              182938  6 sg,usb_storage,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod,firewire_sbp2
```

Are there any other modules I should try to load?

Comment: Is this with a Debian kernel, or one you've built yourself? Do you have the `cdrom` module loaded? Also, do you have any custom config in `/etc/modprobe.d`? E.g., maybe something disabling libata.atapi_enabled? Does dmesg show any evidence of your PATA controller?

Comment: This is strange. Usually the installer will configure this for you. How did you do the installation?

Comment: I am using debian kernel and have done all the upgrades through apt-get upgrade / apt-get dist-upgrade - no customisation of modprobe.d

Comment: The installation was done quite a long time ago using normal debian installer v 6.x something I think.

Comment: Thanks for the advice derobert - I added some info in the OP.

Comment: What is the output of "ls -l | grep sr"?

Comment: enedil, I assume you mean lsmod | grep sr?

Comment: What's in your /etc/fstab?